# ListView inside scrollview does not set to wrap_content

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, scrollview

Look, I know this is a bad idea to put a list view inside scrollview, but, for some reason, I have to do this.

I have a view with 3 fragments, which are inside a scrollview,

```
<scrollview>
    <framelayout></framelayout> -> each framelayout is fragment container
    <framelayout></framelayout>
    <framelayout></framelayout>
<scrollview>
```

the first fragment that I inflate contains a listview inside it

The problem is that **it won't set the height dynamically** even if I set the `framelayout` height to `wrap_parent`. I have to set the height manually after the view has finished rendering then calculating the height of the content..

My Question , is there a way so that the listview inside the fragment will be set to `wrap_parent` so I don't have to manually calculate the height every time the adapter inside listview renders ?

Comment: why you aint use custom scroll views that handle situation of embedding a list view inside them?

Answer (score 2):

you can write a new custom View extends ListView , and override the method of onMeasure() like this:

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE>>2,MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link.It fix your bug.

[Make listview to be scrolled which is inside of ScrollView](http://kiddyandroid.blogspot.in/2016/04/to-make-listview-to-be-scrolled-inside.html)